# How to add filter to a more like this query in Elastic Search?

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to use a More like this query in Elastic Search to find similar documents.  However I need to filter the documents on which the query is executed.

Example below: I want to find blog items that are similar to blog with id 123456, but written by author 120 or author 123.

When executing this query, I get back similar blogs from ALL authors and thus not filtered ...

```
{
  "query":{
    "more_like_this" : {

        "fields" : ["body" ],  
        "docs" : [
              {
                "_id" : "123456"
              }
            ],
        "percent_terms_to_match" : 0.4,
            "min_term_freq" : 1
      }
  }
 },

"filter":{
  "and":[            
          {
            "type":{ "value":"blog" }
          },
          {
            "terms":{ "authorId": ["120", "123"] }
          }
        ]
}
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try filtered query like this:

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
                "more_like_this": {
                    "fields": [
                        "body"
                    ],
                    "docs": [
                        {
                            "_id": "123456"
                        }
                    ],
                    "percent_terms_to_match": 0.4,
                    "min_term_freq": 1
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "and": [
                    {
                        "type": {
                            "value": "blog"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "terms": {
                            "authorId": [
                                "120",
                                "123"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps...!

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer is for earlier versions of ElasticSearch. This one works great on 2.x+ also not using any depreciated APIs

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
                "more_like_this": {
                    "fields": ["meta.keywords"],
                    "like": [{"_id": "5732759249d2b21f95641d50"}]
                }
            },
            "filter" : {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [                            
                        {"match": { "foo.bar": "A"}},
                        {"match": { "baz": "new"}}
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```